# NiFi exception for UI display.. Cant find a solution to this. NOOB

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

Let me tell you a little background to this. I have Apache NiFi 1.3.0 installed in a VM. Nifi does acquire Java. The java version is below.

`murtaza@wildcat:/nifi-1.3.0/logs$ java -version`

`openjdk version "9-internal
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)`

The moment I run or start NIFI it starts but does not show up the UI. Below is the output when the NIfi starts.

`murtaza@wildcat:/nifi-1.3.0/bin$ sudo sh nifi.sh start
nifi.sh: 88: nifi.sh: source: not found`

`Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
NiFi home: /nifi-1.3.0`

`Bootstrap Config File: /nifi-1.3.0/conf/bootstrap.conf`

The problem here is that the nifi does not show its port localhost:8080 when I display the ports. Here it is

`murtaza@wildcat:/nifi-1.3.0/bin$ sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1299/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1090/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1299/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1090/sshd`

Therefore, I cannot open the localhost:8080/nifi in a browser and it does give an error.

I have tried everything but it doenst help me anyway. I think there is a prob with the java jre or jdk.. or maybe the java directory. IDK how to read these error logs file also. The log file **nifi-app.log** . Below is the log file output.

`2017-07-24 14:46:29,363 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor: Provider org.apache.nifi.processors.enrich.QueryDNS could not be instantiated
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor: Provider org.apache.nifi.processors.enrich.QueryDNS could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(java.base@9-internal/ServiceLoader.java:381)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$800(java.base@9-internal/ServiceLoader.java:220)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathIterator.nextService(java.base@9-internal/ServiceLoader.java:835)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$RestrictedIterator.next(java.base@9-internal/ServiceLoader.java:540)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$2.next(java.base@9-internal/ServiceLoader.java:940)
        at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.loadExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:138)
        at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.discoverExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:113)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:699)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:160)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:267)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.nifi.processors.enrich.QueryDNS (in unnamed module @0x490c7a83) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory (in module jdk.naming.dns) because module jdk.naming.dns does not export com.sun.jndi.dns to unnamed module @0x490c7a83
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.enrich.QueryDNS.<init>(QueryDNS.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base@9-internal/NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.base@9-internal/Constructor.java:453)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(java.base@9-internal/Class.java:550)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathIterator.nextService(java.base@9-internal/ServiceLoader.java:833)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
2017-07-24 14:46:29,371 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2017-07-24 14:46:29,372 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).`

Can anyone kindly help me with this.. I cant understand the log files. Can you please help me out with this.. Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems it's a bug in openjdk 9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153156

i know that apache nifi 1.3 built with java 8 so try to use java 8 instead of java 9

Comment: It worked. Awesome. Downgrading it to java 8 did the job. Seems like Nifi1.3 isn't compatible with java 9 yet. Although their official sites say that it supports java 8 and the latest version. Well Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can comment code at line 88 (below code), and it will work.

```
# if [ -f /etc/os-release ]
# then
#     source /etc/os-release
# fi
```